# Uploading CSV from S3 to MySQL RDS first row truncated

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3, amazon-rds, amazon-data-pipeline

I've created a Data Pipeline in AWS that uploads a CSV file in S3 to a table in a MySQL db

The data pipeline is working partially, it creates the table, and inserts the CSV file into the table, however it returns an error for the first row.

```
Incorrect integer value: '? 1' for column 'Case' at row 1
```

The first row is truncated, then continues to upload the rest.

I've checked my table data types, csv data types, there is also no header row.
Not sure where the `'?1'` is coming from

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well the first row in csv might contains the column name inspite of the data. SO you have to ignore first row. Can you paste your code here.